# How to animate a text reveal sliding up with perspective?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, text, header

My experience with css animation is minimal and I have a friend that wants this specific animation for the header title of his page.

This is the page example.
https://www.sendpotion.com/

The message:
"Personalize
Videos at Scale"

Appears from bottom behind and has curve.

I have tried to  hack their styles but i could not achieve it.

Can somebody help me with an example or a library?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using GSAP (https://greensock.com/gsap/), you can use that or also look into Framer and their motion library